# Averaging number of lattice points in a box over a family of lattices

Tags: nt.number-theory, lattices, geometry-of-numbers

Consider the diophantine equation
$$ x_1y_1^3 + \dots + x_s y_s^3 = 0. $$

For fixed $\mathbf{y}$ with coprime coordinates this is a $s-1$ dimensional lattice $\Lambda(\mathbf{y})$. Let $N(X)$ denote the number of integer points in this lattice with $\max |x_i| \leq X$. Then we should have
$$ N(X) - \frac{cX^{s-1}}{d(\Lambda(\mathbf{y}))}\ll 1+ \frac{X^{s-2}}{\lambda_1 \dotsc\lambda_{s-2}},$$

where the $\lambda_i$ denote the successive minima. I would now like to sum  this error term over coprime vectors $\mathbf{y}$ with $\max |y_i| \leq Y$. Assume $X \geq Y$.

It may happen that $\lambda_{s-1}$  is big (and conversely by Minkowski's theorem the product of the other successive minima small) - that is of size $d(\Lambda(\mathbf{y}))$. I would like to show that this can not happen too often in the sense that the terms where $\lambda_1$ is small do not occur on average often. Any input on how that might be achieved is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Edit:

Actually $c(\mathbf{y})$ just depends on the used volume which in my case is the box with sidelength $2X$. I replaced it with just a $c$ to avoid confusion.
We have $d(\Lambda(\mathbf{}y))=||\mathbf{y}||_2$ for primitive vectors $\mathbf{y}$. And $d(\Lambda(\mathbf{}y))$ is bounded above and below the product of the successive minima.

If we sum the leading term 
$$ \frac{cX^{s-1}}{d(\Lambda(\mathbf{y}))} $$
over lattices in question we get as main term
$$ CX^{s-1}Y^{s-3}. $$ If $X$ is large against $Y$, since we have 
$$ \lambda_i \gg 1,$$ we may use the trivial error term $X^{s-2}Y^{s}$. Hence if $X\geq Y^{3+\delta}$ this would suffice. The idea was that one might be able to exploit the fact that $\lambda_1 \dotsc \lambda_{s-2}$ should not always be small.

Comment: What do you get when you sum $N(X)$ over the lattices/vectors in question? What is the relationship between the sizes of $X$ and $Y^3$? Can you clarify your notation—what is $c(y)$, and is it correct that $d(\Lambda(y)) = \lambda_1\cdots\lambda_{s-1}$?

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I added some more infos.